# how to use Multiple PrimeNG Galleria in angular 2 *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<li *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img src="assets/images/{{image.href}}" />
</li>
```

this is my code, every **li loops** inside get the **multiple images** from **database**,

how to use the **PrimeNG Galleria** in the **li loop.** ?

the default **PrimeNG Galleria** HTML code is

```
<p-galleria [images]="images" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313"></p-galleria>
```

the default **PrimeNG Galleria** Component.ts code is

```
images: any[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.images = [];
    this.images.push({source:'assets/img/gal1.jpg', alt:'Description 1', title:'Title 1'});
    this.images.push({source:'assets/img/gal2.jpg', alt:'Description 2', title:'Title 2'});
    this.images.push({source:'assets/img/gal3.jpg', alt:'Description 3', title:'Title 3'});
    this.images.push({source:'assets/img/gal4.jpg', alt:'Description 4', title:'Title 4'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No Need for list

.
Use simple div

```
<div  *ngFor="let image of images">
    <p-galleria [images]="images" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313"></p-galleria>
</div >
```

This should do the job

Comment: li tag not a problem my question is how to push the image.href into the images source

Comment: Create an array of images [] in your component class and push whatever  images you want in a loop to this images array, then use this images in your template